# how to transpose

Tags: sql, oracle

DB:Oracle

I have a few fields,

```
account cost1 cost2 cost3 cost4 cost5
10       $20   $30   $40   $50   $60
20       $100   $200  $300  $400 $500
```

The requirement is,

- if account is 10 then i only need cost1 and cost3
- if account is 20 then i only need cost2 and cost4

result should be something like this,

```
20----10
40----10
200----20
400----20
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select account, cost1 as cost
from t
where account = 10
union all
select account, cost3
from t
where account = 10
union all
select account, cost2
from t
where account = 20
union all
select account, cost4
from t
where account = 20
```